# Cypress Automation: Domain based Javascript execution issue

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress, webautomation

Had an issue while testing on Cypress. 
Issue: The JS file is not getting loaded while testing using Cypress.

- There is a check added to load the **JS file** when one of the window property is set.
- Cypress opens the requested URL into iframes which has its own window object.
  So, the actual window object of the site is different and the Cypress window object is   different.
- Due to this **JS file** is not loading in Cypress browser.
- The window property which is required to load the **JS file** returns value as "undefined" because the Cypress runs the site in its own frame which has its own window object.

Solutions We tried: Which still does not works.
- We tried setting the property of window object from the test itself. 
- Also, tried adding **"chromeWebSecurity": false** to the config file.

```
describe(‘ExampleTest’, () => {
    it('Verify test’, () => {

    cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl )
    cy.login(email, password)

    parent.window.GLOBAL_VAR = true 
    window.GLOBAL_VAR  = true
    parent.window.frames[0].window.GLOBAL_VAR = true
    parent.window.frames[1].window.GLOBAL_VAR= true

    cy.window().then((window) => {
        window.GLOBAL_VAR  = true
        window.frames[0].window.GLOBAL_VAR = true
    }
}
```

Note: 
- GLOBAL_VAR is the property which remains undefined inside the frames.
- The property of parent window is set to true but its frame window property remains ‘undefined’. And Cypress opens the requested URL in frames. So, it does not set the window property. Which in turn does not load the JS.

[Window hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c4OG.png)

Comment: YOu should be able to install a EventListener to your Window object in your app. This can be restricted to those cases where you run your app within cypress. Then you can throw this event during tests. Not sure if this can be handled easier

Comment: Thanks for you help, @JosefBiehler but setting EventListener won't work in this case as we need to set the GLOBAL_VAR property before window is loaded as it is used to load the specific JS file.